# Sending SMS from Android phone connected to Linux

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am trying to get an Android phone connected to a Linux server running Nagios to send out SMS when a system it is monitoring goes down.

The Android version on the phone is 7(not rooted). I have adb installed on the Linux computer and the phone is connected over a USB cable.

I have tried with the following code:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:$mobile_number --es sms_body $sms_text --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

It works fine for a while and somewhere along the way it stops working. It types the message, which I can see on the phone's screen but fails to send.

When I run the commands manually from the command line I get an error similar to:

> "Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to
>   the front"

I was wondering if there is a better way to send SMS from a Linux computer? I could install a suitable application on the phone if needed, I just need a reliable way.

Comment: I would suggest to add a pause between each command... at least 2 seconds... Maybe, keyevents are running while the activity was not fully created and the keyevent is not processed as you want..

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution but you will have to create your own app (very very simple one).

Create an new app and copy-paste this code into the `onCreate()` method of the MainActivity:

```
if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
    String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Build and install the app on your phone. Then you would simply do this :

```
adb shell am start -n "com.example.your_app/.MainActivity" -e number XXXXXXXXXX -e message "Hello World !"
```